# Best way to loop through multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, loops

I move dictionary

```
user = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    'age': '11',
    'place': 'moon',
    'dob': '12/12/12'
}

user1 = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': '13',
    'place': 'Earth',
    'dob': '12/12/12'
}
```

What is the best way to loop through each user by adding 1? So the next user would be user2.

Thanks

Comment: When you start numbering variables, you're doing something wrong. Please use a list. That's arguably the "best way" to loop over anything.

Comment: Thanks very much!
Working great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of assigning user1 as the variable name for the dictionary you could create a new dictionary variable where the key is the user and the value is a nested dictionary with all of the information about the users like this:

```
users = {
    'user1': {
         'name': 'John',
         'age': '13',
         'place': 'Earth',
         'dob': '12/12/12'
         },
    'user2': {
         'name': 'Bob',
         'age': '11',
         'place': 'moon',
         'dob': '12/12/12'
         }
     ...}
```

Then you can iterate over the nested dictionary for all users user1, user2,...userN instead of assigning each user to its own variable.

Update:
Here's how you would then loop across the nested dictionary:

```
for k, v in users.items():
    print(k, v)
```

where k is the key ('user1', 'user2' etc.) and v is the nested dictionary containing the information for the user.

Comment: You provided the right answer - but you forgot to loop in - even if it appears dumb, you should add an example of how to loop into your dict to really answers OP

Comment: Thank you for the help - I decided to go with your solution. @Arount It's okay, I have done it.

Comment: @smye it's also for future users and "teach" to this new fellow what SO expect as a good answer - anyway good you had your answer :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to deal with this (in my opinion is having the dicts in a list.
 I'd only use dictionaries if the keys actually mean something. The below is also a valid dict to convert to json.

```
users = [{
             'name': 'John',
             'age': '13',
             'place': 'Earth',
             'dob': '12/12/12'
             },
            {
             'name': 'Bob',
             'age': '11',
             'place': 'moon',
             'dob': '12/12/12'
             }]
```

user1 is users[0], user2 is users[1] ...

users.append({...}) to add more etc.

And if you loop and want the user number:

```
for ind,item in enumerate(users):
    print("user{}".format(ind+1))
```

Prints:

```
user1
user2
```

Answer (score 2):

[zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) is the best way to iterate over multiple arrays,list and json objects.
Using zip(), we can iterate over given two json dictionary with a single for loop.

```
import json
user = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    'age': '11',
    'place': 'moon',
    'dob': '12/12/12'
}

user1 = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': '13',
    'place': 'Earth',
    'dob': '12/12/12'
}
for (u, u1) in zip(user, user1): 
     print(user[u], user1[u1])
```

### Result

Bob John

11 13

moon Earth

12/12/12 12/12/12

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is actually searching for a solution to properly loop through multiple dicts without creating unnecessary copies or using nested loops...

```
from itertools import chain

d0 = dict(a=1, b=2)
d1 = dict(c=3, d=4)

for key, val in chain(d0.items(), d1.items()):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, using [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) depending on your scope:

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(globals()['user' + str(i)])
... 
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': '11', 'place': 'moon', 'dob': '12/12/12'}
{'name': 'John', 'age': '13', 'place': 'Earth', 'dob': '12/12/12'}
```

But as stated in the comments, I would recommend using a list:

```
>>> users = [user0, user1]
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(users[i])
... 
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': '11', 'place': 'moon', 'dob': '12/12/12'}
{'name': 'John', 'age': '13', 'place': 'Earth', 'dob': '12/12/12'}
```

Comment: In the second loop  `for user in users` is way better than using indexes!

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that I did for starting to compare 2 dictionaries.:

```
    MENU = {
        "espresso": {
            "ingredients": {
                "water": 50,
                "milk": 0,
                "coffee": 18,
            },
            "cost": 1.5,
        },
        "latte": {
            "ingredients": {
                "water": 200,
                "milk": 150,
                "coffee": 24,
            },
            "cost": 2.5,
        },
        "cappuccino": {
            "ingredients": {
                "water": 250,
                "milk": 100,
                "coffee": 24,
            },
            "cost": 3.0,
        }
    }
    resources = {
        "water": 300,
        "milk": 200,
        "coffee": 100,
    }   

    Choice_Ingredients=MENU["ingredients"]

    for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in zip(Choice_Ingredients.items(), resources.items()):
            
             print (f"{key1} : {value1} \n{key2} : {value2}")
```

The above code prints.:

```
>water : 200 
>water : 300
>milk : 150 
>milk : 200
>coffee : 24 
>coffee : 100
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you should use chainmap to iterate through multiple dictionaries.
import the chainmap from itertools like:

```
from itertools import Chainmap
d1 = {'k1': 'v1'}
d2 = {'k2': 'v2'}

for k, v in (d1,d2).items():
  print(k,v)
```